# If Monday then filter the last 3 days, if not, filter the last day

Tags: vba, variables, filter, pivot

Trying to build something that checks what day is today and then filters a pivot table based on this. If today is Monday then, the pivot needs to be filtered on the "Report date" of the last 3 days (Friday/Saturday/Sunday). If any other day, the "Report date" needs to be filtered on the previous day only.

```
If Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) = 1 Then
    rDate = Format(Now() - 3, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Else: rDate = Format(Now() - 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If
```

But I do not know how to use this variable to create the filter after.
Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivot()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim DateStart As Double, DateFinish As Double
Dim PvtFld As PivotField
Dim PvtItm As PivotItem

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' set the Pivot-Table Object
' Modify "Sheet1" to where your Pivot-Table lies, and "PivotTable1" to your Pivot-Table name
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

' set the Pivot Field Object
' Modify "Date" to the Pivot Field's name you want to filter
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Date")

If Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) = 1 Then
    DateStart = DateAdd("d", -3, Date) ' the first date in the range of dates to display (current date -3 days)
Else
    DateStart = DateAdd("d", -1, Date) ' the first date in the range of dates to display (current date -1 day)
End If
DateFinish = DateAdd("d", -1, Date) ' the last date in the range of dates to display (current date -1 day)

PvtFld.ClearAllFilters ' clear all existing filters
For Each PvtItm In PvtFld.PivotItems ' loop through items in PivotField
    ' check if the value of the date is between the scanned ranges of dates (1 day, or 3 days)
    If CDbl(DateValue(PvtItm.Name)) >= DateStart And CDbl(DateValue(PvtItm.Name)) <= DateFinish Then
        PvtItm.Visible = True
    Else
        PvtItm.Visible = False
    End If
Next PvtItm

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```